# Absolute div escaping its container

Tags: jquery-ui, position, jquery-ui-tabs, absolute, jquery-ui-accordion

http://micheresources.com/html/miche-u/lead-with-style

Click on "Lead With Style" and it should automatically place you under "Calls 1-6".

As you can probably see, the content on the right-hand side of the page is escaping its container. It's not a float issue, but probably something to do with absolute positioning and display.

I'm using jQuery tabs and jQuery accordion. I found this script and modified it, but it isn't working:

```
$(function() { 
    var parentHeight = $('#accordion').height(), 
        childHeight = $('.ui-tabs-panel').height(); 

    if (parentHeight <= childHeight) { 
        $('#accordion').height(childHeight); 
    } 
});
```

Here is the relevant CSS:

```
#main-content {
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,.5);
    padding: 35px;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.1);
    border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    -khtml-border-radius: 10px;
    position: relative;
}

#accordion { position: relative; }
    #accordion h3 {
        width: 220px;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 4px 0 8px;
        font-size: 1.1em;
        cursor: pointer;
        outline: none;
        color: #6a6a6a;
    }

#accordion > div > ul {
    width: 205px;
    padding: 0 0 7px 15px;
}
    #accordion > div > ul li {
        background: url(../images/arrow.png) left 9px no-repeat;
        padding: 6px 0 6px 10px; 
        outline: none;
    }
        #accordion > div > ul li a { font: .9em Arial, "Lucida Grande", sans-serif; outline: none; }
        #accordion > div > ul li a:link, #accordion > div > ul li a:visited { color: #7d7d7d; }
        #accordion > div > ul li a:hover, #accordion > div > ul li.ui-state-active a { color: #64d1e7; }
        #accordion > div > ul li.ui-state-active a { text-decoration: underline; }

#accordion > div > div.ui-tabs-panel, #accordion > div > section {
    width: 560px;
    position: absolute;
    top: -23px;
    right: 0;
}
    #accordion > div > div.ui-tabs-panel span.button, #accordion > div > section span.button { float: right; display: inline-block; }
    #accordion > div > div.ui-tabs-panel h4, #accordion > div > section h4 { margin-bottom: 7px; font-size: 1.5em; color: #6a6a6a; }
    #accordion > div > div.ui-tabs-panel h5, #accordion > div > section h5 { margin-bottom: 15px; font-size: .9em; color: #a6a6a6; }
    #accordion > div > div.ui-tabs-panel p, #accordion > div > section p {
        font: 1em Helvetica, Arial, "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
        color: #757575;
        line-height: 1.5em;
    }
```

And the HTML:

```
<div id="main-content">
    <h1>Welcome, Leader!</h1>
    <hr />
    <h2>SECTIONS</h2>
    <div id="accordion">
        <h3>Coaching and Mentoring</h3>
        <div id="sec-1">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="sections/lead-with-style/1-1">Under Construction</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <h3>Lead With Style</h3>
        <div id="sec-2">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="sections/lead-with-style/2-1">Calls 1-6</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <h3>Moving Up</h3>
        <div id="sec-3">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="sections/lead-with-style/3-1">Compensation Plan Videos</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <h3>Dan Clark Leadership</h3>
        <div id="sec-4">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="sections/lead-with-style/4-1">Tab 1</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <h3>New Rep Coaching</h3>
        <div id="sec-5">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="sections/lead-with-style/5-1">Advisor Checklist</a></li>
                <li><a href="sections/lead-with-style/5-2">Six Weekly Emails</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <h3>Monthly Meetings</h3>
        <div id="sec-6">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="sections/lead-with-style/6-1">How to Hold an Effective Meeting</a></li>
                <li><a href="sections/lead-with-style/6-2">Monthly Basic Meeting Agenda</a></li>
                <li><a href="sections/lead-with-style/6-3">Monthly Agenda Details</a></li>
                <li><a href="sections/lead-with-style/6-4">More Info</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <h3>Communication Skills</h3>
        <div id="sec-7">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="sections/lead-with-style/7-1">Under Development</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Absolute position is certainly ruining your party, so let's fix that with some CSS and jQuery:

```
.ui-tabs-panel {
  overflow: auto;
}
```

which will give us a scroll bar if the content is "too long". What's too long? That's where we use jQuery:

```
$('.ui-tabs-panel').css("height", $('#accordion').innerHeight()+"px");
```

We force the tab content to have the same height as are accordion. Now we have a metric for "too much" and it'll look correct (although the scrollbar may not be aesthetically pleasing, of course).

Note that in order to preserve this behaviour with a less rigidly sized container, you'll have to rebind the height whenever the browser is resized, which will need some more jQuery. Let's wrap the above code:

```
function makeAccordionContentFit() {
  $('.ui-tabs-panel').css("height", $('#accordion').innerHeight()+"px");
}

// make it work right now!
makeAccordionContentFit();

// also make it work on document resize...
$(document).resize(makeAccordionContentFit);
```

Your page looks like it has a fixed-size container, but it's always good plan for the future.

Comment: Ah, that didn't do it. The page container isn't a fixed size either; the #main-content div expands to the size of the accordion, but not to the size of the tab, which is what I'm trying to do. Thanks for the reply!